# I am trying to implement a neural network using Keras. My error is listed below:

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

ERROR: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape (25, 1)

Input condition: randomly two set of data set, each one with 50 data patterns,  in two dimensions x1 and x2. One data set has 0 <= x1 <= 3  and  0 <= x2 <= 3  with target of 0, and the second data set has 6 <= x1 <= 9 and  6 <= x2 <= 9  with target of 1.

The following is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=[2])])
model.add(Dense(units= 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units= 1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

x1 = list(np.random.uniform(0,3,50))
x2 = list(np.random.uniform(0,3,50))
labels = [0 for i in range(50)]                                                 #target is set  to 0

                                                                                #concatenating the list with tother condition of <6<=9
x1 = x1+ list(np.random.uniform(6,9,50))                                        #Plotting the points between 6 to 9 and putting 50 random points 
x2 += list(np.random.uniform(6,9,50))
labels += [1 for i in range(50)]
x = np.append(x1, x2, axis= -1)
print (x)

x_train = np.array(x, dtype='float64')
tr = np.array(t, dtype='float64'
```

)

I have tried other possible syntax too like:

```
x1 = []

x2 = []
t = []
for i in range(50):
  x1.append(random.uniform(0,3))
  x2.append(random.uniform(0,3))
for i in range(50):
  x1.append(random.uniform(6,9))
  x2.append(random.uniform(6,9))
for i in range(50):
  t.append(0)
for i in range(50):
  t.append(1)

x1 = np.random.uniform([0,3,size=(50,2))
x2 = np.random.uniform([6,9,size=(50,2))
```

It shows the error in the last line i.e the (model.fit) line.

Comment: I am confused, you have no model.fit() line. I do not see .fit() called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things I don't understand. You have no .fit() line, so I don't know what you are asking. You repeatedly create arrays and then override them. You also have several unused variables (why?). Finally you import from both keras and tensorflow.keras, these are completely separate packages. Here is an attempt of what I think you were trying to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np

#Data
X = np.random.random((10_000,2)) #10_000 2-unit vectors. 
Y = np.random.random((10_000,))  #10_000 numbers. 

#Model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,'sigmoid'),
])
model.compile('sgd','mse')

#Training
model.fit(X,Y,256,10)
```